# How do I get thunderbird to use my gpg keyring?

Tags: thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

Since the latest "improve"ments to Thunderbird, I now have two different gpg keyrings instead of just one. How can I get Thunderbird to use the gpg keyring in ~/.gnupg, instead of its own internal one?

Comment: AFAIK this is only partially possible: https://blog.nicohood.de/use-thunderbird-78-with-system-gnupg-keyring

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300459/how-does-mozilla-thunderbird-handles-my-key-and-can-it-import-directly-from-gpg

Answer (score 5):

You can Thunderbird configure to use GnuPGP's gpg-agent, and therfore make Thunderbird use the keys of GnuPGP.

Set

> **mail.openpgp.allow_external_gnupg**

to `true` in Thunderbird's configuration editor. The editor is available via:

> Thunderbird → Settings → General → Config Editor

See https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:OpenPGP:Smartcards#Allow_the_use_of_external_GnuPG for more information. Note that this wiki page is about smartcards, but the linked section is generic about using gpg-agent with thunderbird.

Comment: Doesn't work. Key management shows Thunderbird's keys only, and the agent is never called when signing.

Comment: FWIW, it works for me. Did you configure the account identity ot use the "External GNuPG Key"?

Comment: I found the option but it's useless to me. Thunderbird still requires all public keys to be held in its own database, requiring extra synchronisation.

Comment: Works for me, but had to tell TB to use the external key as described in the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: **you can't**. There is no way to have Mozilla Thunderbird utilize your existing gpg keyring for public keys.

Per [this thread](https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/e2ee/T0110b6f340d1c026):

> Public keys have to be imported into Thunderbird OpenPGP. There is no
> way around that. This is a design choice.

This is pretty mind-blowing. Can we go back to enigmail? Now we all have to maintain two distinct databases with the same content storing my contact's trusted keys and their level of trust :(

If we meet someone in-person and are able to verify their fingerprint and identity, we have to update it in more than one place. If we forget, then it's a nightmare trying to keep it all in-sync.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you can't use your gnupg keys with Thunderbird. There is an advance configuration option that makes Thunderbird using the gpg-agent. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1795430/18192).